How to put a caption into a tcolorbox?
As an example would be much better than a long explanation, here is an MWE of what I would like to achieve, this consists of inserting the counter or the entiere caption inside a tcolorbox. I specify that I am not looking for the blend into option (/tcb/new/blend into), my case is different :
\documentclass{book}
% Allow the usage of UTF-8 characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Allow the usage of graphics (.png, .jpg)
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][red]{on line, arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black, boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt, boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt}

% Start the document
\begin{document}

% Create a new 1st level heading
\chapter*{Main Heading}

First example : \\

\mybox{Figure 1.1 : The label is in the box} \\

Second example : \\

\mybox[green]{Table 1.1 :} Only the counter is in the box

\end{document}


Thank you is advance for your help ^^
Regards.

off-topic: don't load inputenc; never end a paragraph with \\ .

you don't have any figure environments in your code. do you want to use \mybox inside figure environments? or do you want the box to be a figure itself i.e. you want to put your graph or whatever in the box, too?

Hello. Yes I want to use \mybox inside figure or table environment. But the figure / graph is not included in the box, only counter or entiere caption (counter + label) must be included in the box.

You could patch the internal \@makecaption and \@caption commands, this is only working when you don't load other package which redefine the \@makecaption and \@caption command. Such as caption package which will make patches invalid. Redefined \caption command have following syntax:
\caption<*>(<color>)[<title in lof/lot>]{<title in text>}
Using star version, box will put on the counter only. Without star the box will put on the whole caption only.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\myboxc}[1][red]{on line,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black, boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt, boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt}
\newtcbox{\myboxf}[1][red]{on line,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black, boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt, boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt}
\newif\ifboxcapcounter
\boxcapcounterfalse
\newcommand{\boxcapcounter}{\boxcapcountertrue}
\newcommand{\boxcapfull}{\boxcapcounterfalse}
\newcommand{\capboxcol}{red}
\newcommand{\adjustparboxwidth}{-2pt}
\let\oldcaption\caption
\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{s D(){red} o m}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\boxcapcounter}{\boxcapfull}%
\ifblank{#2}{\renewcommand{\capboxcol}{red}}{\renewcommand{\capboxcol}{#2}}%
\IfValueTF{#3}{%
\oldcaption[#3]{#4}%
}{%
\oldcaption{#4}
}%
}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\ifboxcapcounter\let\myboxf\@gobblethree\let\adjustparboxwidth\relax\else\let\myboxc\@gobblethree\fi}{}{}
%path command for caption within one line
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1: #2}{\myboxf[\capboxcol]{\myboxc[\capboxcol]{#1:} #2}}{}{}
%path command for caption more than one line
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1: #2\par}{\myboxf[\capboxcol]{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth\adjustparboxwidth}{\myboxc[\capboxcol]{#1:} #2}}}{}{}% \dimexpr\linewidth\adjustparboxwidth = \dimexpr\linewidth-2pt is due to the left=1pt and right=1pt in your tcbox settings,otherwise you will have overfull hbox
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter*{Main Heading}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1 & 2 \\\hline
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
    \caption(blue)[title in lot]{Caption with super super super  super super super  super super super  super super super long title}
    \caption*(green){Caption short}
    \label{tab:label}
\end{table}
\myboxf{everything is active in local}

\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-plain}
    \caption*(yellow){Caption with short title}
    \caption[title in lof]{Caption with short title}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
\myboxc{everything is active in local}

\end{document}



Since you solved this problem, I'll check your remark ✔️. But in fact, I'm using the caption package. If you have an idea of how to solve this problem with caption package, you can go here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/731567/how-to-put-a-caption-into-a-tcolorbox-v2-with-caption-package-activated thank you
