How to put a caption into a tcolorbox (v2) with caption package activated
I'm trying to get this result but with the caption package activated. This is the continuation of the following post : How to put a caption into a tcolorbox (v1)
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\myboxc}[1][red]{on line,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black, boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt, boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt}
\newtcbox{\myboxf}[1][red]{on line,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black, boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt, boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt}
\newif\ifboxcapcounter
\boxcapcounterfalse
\newcommand{\boxcapcounter}{\boxcapcountertrue}
\newcommand{\boxcapfull}{\boxcapcounterfalse}
\newcommand{\capboxcol}{red}
\newcommand{\adjustparboxwidth}{-2pt}
\let\oldcaption\caption
\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{s D(){red} o m}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\boxcapcounter}{\boxcapfull}%
\ifblank{#2}{\renewcommand{\capboxcol}{red}}{\renewcommand{\capboxcol}{#2}}%
\IfValueTF{#3}{%
\oldcaption[#3]{#4}%
}{%
\oldcaption{#4}
}%
}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\ifboxcapcounter\let\myboxf\@gobblethree\let\adjustparboxwidth\relax\else\let\myboxc\@gobblethree\fi}{}{}
%path command for caption within one line
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1: #2}{\myboxf[\capboxcol]{\myboxc[\capboxcol]{#1:} #2}}{}{}
%path command for caption more than one line
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1: #2\par}{\myboxf[\capboxcol]{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth\adjustparboxwidth}{\myboxc[\capboxcol]{#1:} #2}}}{}{}% \dimexpr\linewidth\adjustparboxwidth = \dimexpr\linewidth-2pt is due to the left=1pt and right=1pt in your tcbox settings,otherwise you will have overfull hbox
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter*{Main Heading}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1 & 2 \\\hline
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
    \caption(blue)[title in lot]{Caption with super super super  super super super  super super super  super super super long title}
    \caption*(green){Caption short}
    \label{tab:label}
\end{table}
\myboxf{everything is active in local}

\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-plain}
    \caption*(yellow){Caption with short title}
    \caption[title in lof]{Caption with short title}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
\myboxc{everything is active in local}

\end{document}


Thank you in advance,
Sincerely.

Note that the linked solution replaces \caption with a new command with more arguments, whereas the caption package retains the original arguments and uses \captionsetup to change options.  OTOH, one can use \DeclareCaptionFormat to make almost any change.

As commented by @John, with caption package it is even easier to implement. Here is an example:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\capboxbgcolor}{red!10!white}
\newcommand{\setcapboxbgcolor}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\capboxbgcolor}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\capboxfmcolor}{red!50!black}
\newcommand{\setcapboxfmcolor}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\capboxfmcolor}{#1}%
}
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{on line,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=\capboxbgcolor,colframe=\capboxfmcolor, boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt, boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt,#1}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{boxfull}{\sbox0{#1#2#3}\ifdim\wd0>\linewidth\mybox{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1#2#3}}\else\mybox{#1#2#3}\fi}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{boxcounter}{\sbox0{#1#2}\ifdim\wd0=0pt\relax#1#2#3\par\else\mybox{#1#2}#3\par\fi}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter*{Main Heading}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{format=boxcounter}\setcapboxbgcolor{green!10}\setcapboxfmcolor{green!50!black}
\caption[title in lot]{Caption with super super super  super super super  super super super  super super super long title}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1 & 2 \\\hline
        3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:label}
\end{table}

Some contents in between.

\begin{figure}[hb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-plain} 
\captionsetup{format=boxfull}\setcapboxbgcolor{blue!10}\setcapboxfmcolor{blue!50!black}
\caption[title in lof]{Caption with short title}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

Some contents in between.
\end{document}


